# modify node and extract data from xml file in python

Tags: python, xml

I am new with python and I am looking for advices on what is the best approach to do the following task:

I have an xml file looking like this

```
<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009 http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009/index.xsd">
  <memoryMaps>
    <memoryMap>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>description</description>
      <peripheral>
        <name>periph</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <baseAddress>0x0</baseAddress>
        <range>0x8</range>
        <width>32</width>
        <register>
          <name>reg1</name>
          <displayName>reg1</displayName>
          <addressOffset>0x0</addressOffset>
          <size>32</size>
          <access>read-write</access>
          <reset>
            <value>0x00000002</value>
            <mask>0xFFFFFFFF</mask>
          </reset>
          <field>
            
          </field>
          </register>
      </peripheral>
    </memoryMap>
  </memoryMaps>
</component>
```

I want to do some modifications to modify the node of "reset" to become 2 separate nodes, one for "resetValue" and another "resetMask" but keeping same data in "value" and "mask" extracted into "resetValue" and "resetMask" as follow:

```
          ........
          <access>read-write</access>
          <resetValue>0x00000002</resetValue>
          <resetMask>0xFFFFFFFF</resetMask>
          <field>
           .............
```

I managed the part of parsing my xml file with success, now I can't know how to start this first modification.
Thank you to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

code that create 2 sub elements under 'register' and remove the unneeded element 'reset'

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009 http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009/index.xsd">
  <memoryMaps>
    <memoryMap>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>description</description>
      <peripheral>
        <name>periph</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <baseAddress>0x0</baseAddress>
        <range>0x8</range>
        <width>32</width>
        <register>
          <name>reg1</name>
          <displayName>reg1</displayName>
          <addressOffset>0x0</addressOffset>
          <size>32</size>
          <access>read-write</access>
          <reset>
            <value>0x00000002</value>
            <mask>0xFFFFFFFF</mask>
          </reset>
          <field>
            
          </field>
          </register>
      </peripheral>
    </memoryMap>
  </memoryMaps>
</component>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
register = root.find('.//register')
value = register.find('.//reset/value').text
mask = register.find('.//reset/mask').text

v = ET.SubElement(register, 'resetValue')
v.text = value
m = ET.SubElement(register, 'resetMask')
m.text = mask
register.remove(register.find('reset'))

ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009 http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009/index.xsd">
   <memoryMaps>
      <memoryMap>
         <name>name</name>
         <description>description</description>
         <peripheral>
            <name>periph</name>
            <description>description</description>
            <baseAddress>0x0</baseAddress>
            <range>0x8</range>
            <width>32</width>
            <register>
               <name>reg1</name>
               <displayName>reg1</displayName>
               <addressOffset>0x0</addressOffset>
               <size>32</size>
               <access>read-write</access>
               <field />
               <resetValue>0x00000002</resetValue>
               <resetMask>0xFFFFFFFF</resetMask>
            </register>
         </peripheral>
      </memoryMap>
   </memoryMaps>
</component>
```

Comment: Thank you again. The only modification I replaced "root = ET.fromstring(xml)" by "root = tree.getroot()" to make parsing easier.   One problem still is it always place  new created sub elements at the end of node "register" instead of specific location before 'field' element as indicated up!  May be I can look that up

Comment: @lmen - the location of the new elements has no importance and should be ignored.